What's the best practice to implement an alternative to TypeScript `enum`?
I learned from a course that the built-in enum from TypeScript should be avoided. It told me to use the following instead:
const MyEnum = {
  name: 'name',
  email: 'email'
} as const;
type MyEnum = keyof typeof MyEnum;

I understand the benefits of this:

I can always have MyEnum.name as an argument in anywhere that accepts a MyEnum.
I can always use a string literal like 'name' in anywhere that accepts a MyEnum. This avoids the need to import MyEnum when string literal is used.
The Object.keys(MyEnum) will not include both key and value type when MyEnum is composed of numbers instead of string literals.

I want to keep these advantages. But in the current implementation provided by the course, I still need to write a string literal for each key. Is it possible to avoid this? For example, I'm thinking about whether I can create such enum using an array ['name', 'email']?

"I learned from a course that the built-in enum from TypeScript should be avoided" do not substitute advice for critical thinking. Enums have their place, even the TS version of them. Just be aware of the caveats. What is your actual use case? Also as an aside, love your handle FWIW

@JaredSmith: I will edit my question. Thanks for your hints.

"This avoids the need to import MyEnum when string literal is used" you don't have to do that anyway, you can pass a literal where an enum is expected and the compiler will allow it. One of the problems though as you can see from the playground is that it allows too much: there's no way it should let you call baz with a non const number, but it does.

@JaredSmith Pardon? But you're using number as the value type for the enum? When I wrote enum MyEnum { A = 'A', B = 'B' }, then baz('A') causes an error.

@JaredSmith Can you explain the code you provided? How Is it related to my question?

So I didn't realize that string enums are nominally typed but integer enums are not. My example isn't actually relevant to your issue after all.

The simplest way is to simply use unions of string literals:
type MyEnum = "name" | "email";

Is there any feature of enums you are missing from this?
Edit:
If you need to be able to iterate through the possible values of the enum, you can indeed create it from an array:
const myValues = ["name", "email"];
type MyEnum = typeof myValues[number];

I don't really see why it's important to be able to refer to the values using the MyEnum.name syntax, when the "name" is shorter, doesn't require imports, and has no drawbacks that I can think of.
If you really want to, you can probably still do it with something like this (untested, you might need to give it a different name):
const MyEnum = Object.fromEntries(myValues.map(v => [v, v])) as {
  [K in MyEnum]: K;
};


If the OPs use case is a map literal like they posted, then keyof typeof the as const object literal is a better choice.

But what's the use case of a map like in the OP? If the only use for it is to be able to write MyEnum.name, I find it much simpler to write just "name" instead, and it is just as type-safe with unions of string literals.

@GuillaumeBrunerie: In our use case, we found that it's easier to identify/classify what's the source of these constants by MyEnum.name than string literals.

For a user object the OPs entire approach is probably wrong, because there are parts of that data you are going to want to be able to use in other contexts (like anonymized contexts). But there can be other times when it makes sense to have the map be the source-of-truth for the keys.

I've edited my answer to add more information.

"why it's important to be able to refer to the values..." - sometimes it is. A string literal 'name' means roughly nothing, while MistakeSource.NAME means that there was some mistake caused by name entry (in appropriate context, of course). If you have a form with 'name' field, good luck trying to distinguish one from another a couple of months later.

@STerliakov In itself, a string literal means nothing, I agree. But here the idea is that the string literal "name" will have type MyEnum in the situations where it means MyEnum.name, so as long as you can look at the type you know exactly what it means.
